# Computer wouldn't detect WiFi Network - Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

I use Ubuntu 16.04.1. Lenovo Ideapad 310-14ISK.
All of a sudden, there's no Internet connection. 
After restarting my computer 3 or 4 times and restarting the WiFi,
and after typing `sudo service network-manager restart` - nothing worked.

What should I do?

Help much appreciated. Thank you.

---

- `apt-get install --reinstall network-manager` – Nothing happened
- `sudo service network-manager status` – Loaded and Active (running) with a few lines indicating the date
- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager-gnome`

Then I tried to install WICD.
I followed everything and ultimately the Network Manager has disappeared altogether after restarting the computer, and I cannot possibly reinstall it.

UPDATE: Now there's WiFi, but there's no indication for the networks. 
Now I need to somehow reinstall Network Manager offline.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novices but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

(apt-get install --reinstall network-manager)
Should reinstall said program

Comment: I tried this one. Doesn't work...

Comment: What does "sudo service network-manager status" say?

Comment: Loaded and Active (running) with a few lines indicating the date

Comment: Try doing "apt-get install --reinstall network-manager-gnome" as well

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work...

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

Comment: I followed everything and ultimately the Network Manager has disappeared altogether after restarting the computer, and I cannot possibly reinstall it.

Comment: @NEven please edit your post with what you have been doing so its easier to know about it and possibly help you :)

Comment: See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and post a link to the results after pasting at paste.ubuntu.com